# Haptics in VR not working

Tags: vr, oculus

I'm trying to use haptics in VR Scene Inspection in Blender and UPBGE using Oculus, but I don't get it to work.

I've tried "xr.haptic_action_apply". Printing I can get a "True" if I set everything correctly or a "False" if something is wrong, but the vibration never shows in the controller. I've been looking in the documentation and in the console printing "dir" or "help" across the modules.

Is there something I missed to configure? or any tutorial to make it work.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What version precisely of Oculus are you using? Not all versions have haptics.

Comment: I'm using Oculus Rift with touch controllers, Also I have installed Oculus App Version 40.0.0.105.333